# Unix domain socket C client with a .NET NamedPipeServerStream

Tags: c#, c

I am attempting to create a .NET 6 application that uses interprocess communication (IPC) via named pipes using `System.IO.Pipes`, and have a C application communicate with it over the pipe from both Windows and Linux, with the C code being different on Windows and Linux but the C# code being the same for both platforms.
On Windows, I managed to write a working example C client without breaking a sweat, but I'm having issues on Linux. I have found out that `NamedPipeServerStream` on Linux uses Unix domain sockets. The C# named pipe server has a `NamedPipeServerStream` as such:

```
NamedPipeServerStream _serverStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("/tmp/socket", PipeDirection.In);
_serverStream.WaitForConnection();
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
_serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

The C application (representing a named pipe client in this case) uses Unix domain sockets and is written as such:

```
char *socket_path = "/tmp/socket";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    char buf[100];
    int fd,rc;
    if ((fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
    if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        perror("connect error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Enter message: ");
    fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
    write(fd, buf, rc);
    return 0;
}
```

I start the C# server first, then the C client. The client is connected without error codes or exceptions on either side. The `write` call is completed without errors and returns success (0) on the C side, and the `NamedPipeServerStream.Read` returns wíthout errors on the C# side. But the `NamedPipeServerStream.Read` call gives no data - the `Read` call returns 0 bytes read, no matter what I input to the `write` call in the C client. Why could that be?

Comment: Because `rc` has never been initialized.

Comment: Oh wow, what a mistake. Thank you for spotting it! If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `rc` has never been initialized, strictly speaking, the subsequent behavior is undefined. However, the value of `rc` is most likely 0, so the server cannot read any data. I think you originally planned to set it as `strlen(buf)`.